# How to reverse window.isTouchDevice()

Tags: javascript

I have a code:

```
var isTouchDev = window.isTouchDevice();
// tooltip for marker - no HTML - and not shown on touchscreen devices
var tooltip = isTouchDev ? '' : (playerData.nick+', '+ago(last.time, now)+' ago');
```

Tooltip appears when you direct cursor on the object.
I tried to code

```
var tooltip = !isTouchDev? '' : (playerData.nick+', '+ago(last.time, now)+' ago');
```

But after that  tooltip no longer appear even after the cursor.
Is there a simple way to reverse this?
I want to tooltip is always visible.

Comment: Your before and after code is identical. Could you also [create an example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you address it?

Comment: It isn't identical, the second one uses `!` to negate `isTouchDev`

Comment: Obviously touch devices can't show tooltips, as there's no cursor to hover over an element...

Comment: Not quite  identical
First :
var tooltip = isTouchDev
Second:
var tooltip = !isTouchDev

exclamation mark changes the behavior of the program but does not do what I need

Comment: "Obviously touch devices can't show tooltips, as there's no cursor to hover over an element... "
I need visible tooltip without cursor on element

Comment: This isn't enough code to go on.

Comment: Touch devices do have hover states.